# Short date in email templates?

Tags: magento-1.8

We have a long date format in the transitional emails, such as "2015/12/01 00:00..." and I would like to show the date in a short format, like dd/mm/YYYY only. The email variable is:

```
{{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}}
```

If I put "short" instead of "long", does it work?

Answer (score 6):

Using `short` should work, take a look at `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` in /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

```
/**
 * Get formated order created date in store timezone
 *
 * @param   string $format date format type (short|medium|long|full)
 * @return  string
 */
public function getCreatedAtFormated($format)
{
    return Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), $format, true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to override /app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php, create a new function

```
public function getCreatedAtFormatedHideTime($format)
{
    return Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), $format, false);
}
```

So you can call it from mail template:

```
{{var order.getCreatedAtFormatedHideTime('short')}}
```

Output:

01/01/2000

Answer (score 1):

Look at `getCreatedAtFormated` method inside `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` class

```
/**
 * Get formated order created date in store timezone
 *
 * @param   string $format date format type (short|medium|long|full)
 * @return  string
 */
public function getCreatedAtFormated($format)
{
    return Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), $format, true);
}

public function getEmailCustomerNote()
{
    if ($this->getCustomerNoteNotify()) {
        return $this->getCustomerNote();
    }
    return '';
}
```

Comment: It worked fine using {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('short')}}, using "short" as parameter. However, the result was returned with the time and I would like to get just the date, dd/mm/YYYY, the time  doesn't matter for the customer. But... it's already a beginning.